# how can automatically receive new incoming SMS without press button in C#

Tags: c#

example code:

```
private void btnReadSMS_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        try
        {
                string strCommand = "AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"";

                if (this.rbReadAll.Checked)
                {
                    strCommand = "AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"";
                }
                else if (this.rbReadUnRead.Checked)
                {
                    strCommand = "AT+CMGL=\"REC UNREAD\"";
                }
//.............................................. Read all SMS ....................................................
                objShortMessageCollection = objclsSMS.ReadSMS(this.port, strCommand);
                foreach (ShortMessage msg in objShortMessageCollection)
                {

                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { msg.Index, msg.Sent, msg.Sender, msg.Message });
                    item.Tag = msg;
                    lvwMessages.Items.Add(item);
                    //count++;
                    strCmd = msg.Message;
                }
          }
}
```

However, I want to receive the SMS automatically after I connect with the GSM modem. Is there any other way can solve my problem other than this. And I want to know how AT command below works?

```
AT+CNMI=1
AT&W
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to move the code into some sort of service with a thread that keeps running, you will need to tell your code to go and check the modem if there is a new message. I would also recommend you delete the message after you have read it as eventually the SIM will run out of space.

You can find a pretty comprehensive list of the AT commands [here](http://www.developershome.com/sms/). This site is also probably a good place to learn about AT commands. It seems like a lot to read to start out with but use it as you run into issues.
And as from the site mentioed above

> To receive and read SMS messages via AT commands, the GSM/GPRS modem or mobile phone has to support the AT command +CNMI (command name in text: New Message Indications to TE. TE stands for Terminal Equipment, which is the equipment that controls the GSM/GPRS modem or mobile phone. For example, a PC / computer), +CMGL (command name in text: List Messages), or +CMGR (command name in text: Read Messages).
>
> The AT command +CNMI is used to specify how newly arrived SMS messages should be handled. You can tell the GSM/GPRS modem or mobile phone either to forward newly arrived SMS messages directly to the PC, or to save them in message storage and then notify the PC about their locations in message storage.

However your code looks very familiar to this page [here](http://read.pudn.com/downloads186/sourcecode/comm/sms/874050/SMSapplication/SMSapplication/SMSapplication.cs__.htm)

Sometimes using AT commands with modems can be a bit messy to start out with, as what works perfectly on one modem might not work so well on another.

The code below(although be it from a dirty scratch pad)might help get you started:

```
public void ProcessModemMessages(string CommPort)
    {
        try
        {
            SerialPort spCommPort = new SerialPort();
            spCommPort.PortName = CommPort;
            spCommPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            spCommPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            spCommPort.DataBits = 8;
            spCommPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            spCommPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            spCommPort.Open();

            if (spCommPort.IsOpen)
            {
                //Seems like entering the pin on the first start up prevents errors....
                spCommPort.WriteLine("AT+CPIN=3434" + "\r\n");
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                spCommPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=0" + "\r\n");//type: 1 Text. 0 PDU
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                spCommPort.ReadExisting();
                while (m_Run)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        spCommPort.WriteLine("AT+CSQ" + "\r\n");
                        Thread.Sleep(200);
                        string sig = spCommPort.ReadExisting();                           

                        spCommPort.WriteLine("AT" + "\r\n");
                        Thread.Sleep(200);
                        spCommPort.WriteLine("ATE" + "\r\n");
                        Thread.Sleep(200);
                        spCommPort.Write("AT+CPMS=\"SM\",\"SM\",\"SM\"" + "\r\n");
                        Thread.Sleep(200);
                        //spCommPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"" + "\r\n");
                        spCommPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGL=4" + "\r\n");
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                        string smsMessages = spCommPort.ReadExisting();
                        if (Environment.UserInteractive)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(smsMessages);
                        }
                        if (smsMessages.Contains("error"))
                        {
                            InsertError(smsMessages);
                        }
                                                 
                        //delete msgs from sim
                        spCommPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGD=1,1" + "\r\n");
                        Thread.Sleep(200);                          
                        
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //error opening modem
                        InsertError("ProcessModemMessages: " + e.ToString());
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //error opening modem
                InsertError("ProcessModemMessages: " + "Error when opening comm port");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            InsertError("ProcessModemMessages: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don´t you put this code in a TIMER event or even in a BackgroundWorker structure?

I believe the TIMER CONTROL will be simpler to you...  Add a timer control into your code, set the lapse (in milliseconds) and put your code within.

Eg.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/C-Sharp-timer/